# hcitool lescan (Bluetooth LE or any bluetooth scan) in docker under Non-Privileged & Non-host Network mode is possible?

Tags: docker, bluetooth, bluez

For a specific task, **I am failing to scan BLE / BlueZ (`hcitool`, `gatttool`, `btdevice-l`) in Docker under non-privileged and Non-Host network mode.**

These are my results (in Debian-Jessie-8.8.0 Host and `debian:jessie docker image`):

```
 root1@73ab53a9268e:/# hciconfig -a
 Can't open HCI socket.: Operation not permitted

 root1@73ab53a9268e:/# bt-device -l
 Couldn't connect to DBus system bus: Could not connect: Connection refused
```

On another image:

```
root2@0d208802d44a:/# hciconfig -a
Can't open HCI socket.: Address family not supported by protocol
```

I even gave ALL-CAP permissions for Docker on Host but still could not make it.

```
docker run --name container-ID --cap-add=ALL -d -v /var/run/docker.sock:/host/var/run/docker.sock -v /dev:/host/dev -v /proc:/host/proc:ro -v /lib/modules:/host/lib/modules:ro -v /usr:/host/usr:ro Image-ID
```

So, is it possible by any chance to scan BLE / BlueZ in docker under Non-Privileged & Non-Host network mode?

Answer (score 0):

Half Success:

With help from Docker Community, I have successfully started DBus Service inside Docker container by logging in Docker as follows :

`docker` `run` `-v /opt/bluetooth:/var/lib/bluetooth` `-v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro` `-v /tmp/$(mktemp -d):/run` `-it` `debian:jessie`

Just looking to start Bluetooth service next... If somebody got any clue, that would be helpful.

Comment: Why did you use so many backticks, breaking your command line into multiple strings?